# How can I present a native UIViewController in React Native swift module

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I integrated 3rd party payment library with pod in swift module in react native, there are no any error with library integration ,

But when i call `self.present` it not presenting payment view

i call present in my swift module as

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
      callback([NSNull() ,resultsDict])
      let phVC = PHViewController()
          phVC.initRequest = req
          phVC.delegate = self
          phVC.isSandBoxEnabled = true. 
          phVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
          self.present(phVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```